# RuntimeError: Did not find any input files matching the glob pattern ['D:\\ML\\Object-Detection\\data\train.record']

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Hey I am working on a tensorflow project. I am using codes from [this website](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) and when I run my `train.py` file I'm getting the below error.

> RuntimeError: Did not find any input files matching the glob pattern
>   ['D:\ML\Object-Detection\data\train.record']

Comment: Try by modifying path: with backword slash: Ex:`D:/ML/Object-Detection/data/train.record`

Answer (score 3):

Changing the slash to '/' worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Being careful with file extension might be helpful for other.

I have generated **.record** while it was required to create **.tfrecord**

And vice versa :)

Answer (score 1):

I found what happened.

instead of using existed **pipeline.config**
I did a download

`!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/research/object_detection/configs/tf2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config`

In this example I used **ssd_mobilenet**, for you, you can change your model name.
check tensorflow object detection api config [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/configs/tf2)

If it's not work yet. **please try to remove '/' and insert infront of directory**